# write in a file in one activity and read it in another activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to write something in a file in one activity and after i try to read it in another activity to show it.
In fact, the user have to enter the recipient's number once. After that, i will enter this recipient's number for him automatically...

I don't know where is my error, i try since yesterday...
Thank you very much for your helps..

package com.example.automatik;

public class AddRecipientNumber extends Activity {

```
//On stocke le n° du destinataire (1)
String FILENAME = "recipientnumber.txt";
String mehmet = "mehmetmehmet";
FileOutputStream fos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_recipient_number);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recipientbutton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {
            EditText textA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recipientedit1);
            String a = textA.getText().toString();
            EditText textB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.recipientedit2);
            String b = textB.getText().toString();

            if(a.equals(b))
            {
                //On stocke le n° du destinataire (2)
                try
                {
                    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(mehmet.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                AlertDialog alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddRecipientNumber.this).create();
                alertdialog.setMessage("You entered these numbers correctly.\nNow, we will move to the second step!");
                alertdialog.setButton("Move", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        sendMove(v);
                    }
                });
                alertdialog.show();
            }
            else
            {
                AlertDialog alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddRecipientNumber.this).create();
                alertdialog.setMessage("These numbers must be identical. \nPlease try again.");
                alertdialog.show();
            } 
        }
    });
}

//Une fois que les numéros entrés sont identiques & que l'utilisateur accepte de passer à la 2nde étape, on lance:
public void sendMove(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddMasterNumber.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and my second activity:

package com.example.automatik;

public class AddMasterNumber extends Activity {

```
String finall;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_master_number);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //setupActionBar(); 

    //On récupère le n° du destinataire stocké
    try
    {
        FileInputStream in = openFileInput("recipientnumber.txt");
        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while(in.read(buffer) != -1)
        {
            fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
        }
        in.close();
        finall = fileContent.toString();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recipienttext3);
    text.setText(finall);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: post logcat error output. That will show where the error is.

Comment: what you want try to achieve. you cant use sharedpreferences instead of ? or  can you  put it application class and access from where you want ?

Comment: QWR: i try to write in a file in one activity and read it in another activity... For example in my first activity the user enter the recipient number & I save it for him in his application. After that, whenever the user need to send SMS to his friend, I enter the recipient's number for him automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need files for what you want to achieve.

Use [Intent.putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in your first `Activity` and `getIntent().getStringExtra(String)` in the other.

**Edit:**

Use SharefPreferences instead: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: i know how to use intent, etc. But I would like to use files because the user have to enter this recipient's number when he uses this application the first time. After that, i would like to save this recipient's number & enter it in my EditText automatically & facilitate user's stuff.

Comment: Intent is only to share data between two applications but i would like to save this data too.

Comment: @forgive90 Than SharedPreferences suggested by QWR will still be easier to work with than directly manipulating files.

Comment: SharedPreferences save data, even when the user close his application?

Comment: @forgive90 Yes. It's a normal xml file underneath easy to use API.

Comment: Okay thank you but don't you know how to read my file in another activity. These two activities are in the same project & the same application too...

Comment: @forgive90 That's fine. Edited question with a link to a good reading about SharefPrefs.

Comment: Okay but can you help me to read a file into an activity another than where i created it?

Comment: @forgive90 I cannot without you posting relevant information, which was asked for at the beginning: `post logcat error output. That will show where the error is. – Neoh`